# Why are lags of the dependent variable a no-no in traditional random effects models?

Tags: mixed-model, panel-data, autoregressive, consistency, lags

[This post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/435947/69508) says:

> Lagged versions of the dependent variable are a no-no in traditional random effects models. The problem is that they are correlated with the random intercept and produce inconsistent estimates of the regression coefficients. This is known as the initial conditions problem.

Is this an inconsistency in the sense of a [consistent estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_estimator), or something else?

When I search for "initial conditions problem" I found the more familiar (to me) topic of [initial value problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_value_problem), which are not 'problems' of logical or estimator consistency *per se*.

Mathematically, what is this problem?

Comment: The grammar of the original title was a bit off; I tried improving it, but feel free to undo the change if I have distorted the intended meaning. Also, do you mean random effects in the econometric or statistical sense? The quoted answer is probably about econometrics. (The terminology of panel data models may be quite confusing, as the same term refers to different objects in econometrics vs. statistics.)

Comment: @richardhardy Thank you for correcting the title. It is an improvement.

Comment: @richardhardy I know very little about economics, so it is definitely possible that I got confused by a name collision in the terminology. I had assumed random effects as in a part of a mixed effects model, which I guess is the statistics meaning. I would accept an answer going over the economics math.